# Display contents of file on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, dynamic

I am looking for a way to display the contents of a directory on an HTML page. I have the following snippet of code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
let directory_name = "/example";
let filenames = fs.readdirSync(directory_name);
console.log("\nFilenames in directory:");
filenames.forEach((file) => {
   console.log("File:", file);
});
```

This will display the contents of the file in the terminal(console) but I am looking for a way to change the "console.log("File:", file)" line into a statement to send the elements to my HTML page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using Linux btw

Comment: Do you already have a page where you would want this to go?

Comment: I have a basic html page set up that I am trying to write to. There is nothing else on the page though

Answer (score 0):

Use the [express.js](https://expressjs.com/) `res.send` function.

Comment: I don't have access to install on my machine...is there a way to do it without

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you've got npm and nodejs you should be able to install it with `npm i express`